# how to plot one graph after another in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to generate plot for each department and security rating, but all get is just one plot with latest values retrieved from dictionary holder:

**my code is here:**

https://codeshare.io/aYleWY

how to get:
graph
graph
graph
... but not as a subplot?

**EDIT**:

Corrected the code, and corrected the bug which repeated same data everywhere, but my plots lost Y axis altogether, any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add the statement [`plt.figure()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) in the beginning of your last for-loop in order to create a new figure on each iteration. Good luck!